# Using "expect" command to run an interactive program fails

Tags: shell, io, expect, fortran

I am trying to solve my question that I've asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609693/429557) using `expect` script instead of file redirection. Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work as well (the same behaviour as described in the question above: I have to run the script below `./driver.exp` multiple times to get the expected result.

Here is the error message:

```
...

 Input > QUIT
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "VOPT\n""
    (file "./driver.exp" line 33)
```

(The full stdout output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/SignificantCell2/505fb7bd5fd2085895f3472585c5c470))

Here is my `driver.exp` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn construct2d

expect "Input"
send "naca0012.dat\n"

expect "Command"
send "SOPT\n"

expect "Input"
send "NSRF\n"

expect "New value"
send "80\n"

expect "Input"
send "RADI\n"

expect "New value"
send "1\n"

expect "Input"
send "NWKE\n"

expect "New value"
send "1\n"

expect "Input"
send "QUIT\n"

expect "Command"
send "VOPT\n"

expect "Input"
send "JMAX\n"

expect "New value"
send "1\n"

expect "Input"
send "YPLS\n"

expect "New value"
send "5\n"

expect "Input"
send "RECD\n"

expect "New value"
send "1E5\n"

expect "Input"
send "QUIT\n"

expect "Command"
send "GRID\n"

expect "Input"
send "SMTH\n"

expect "Command"
send "QUIT\n"

interact
```

Could you please, help me understand why is this happening?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Apparently when you send `QUIT`, the construct2d program quits. And then the next `send` fails because there's no running process to talk to.

Comment: Try using `autoexpect` to generate the expect code.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thank you for the feedback. Do you have an idea why it does quit? because in some case it just runs fine.

Comment: I have no way to even guess. I've never heard of constructed before.

Comment: \*`construct2d`\*